# Exp of big negative numbers

Tags: numerics

I noticed that `Exp` have a strange behaviour with big negative numbers

```
Exp[-Range[1, 700, 0.001]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
Exp[-Range[1, 800, 0.001]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.014877, True}
>
> {1.551377, False}

I understand than `Exp[-800.0]` is less than `$MinMachineNumber`, so I expected that the answer will be 0.0, but it is 3.668*10^-348 wich is not a machine number.

```
MachineNumberQ@Exp[-800.0]
```

> False

What is the best way to work with these numbers? `N@Exp` do nothing.

My current solution is

```
NExp = Exp@Clip[#, {-100.0, 100.0}] &;

NExp[-Range[1, 800, 0.001]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.016354, True}

Moreover, I notice that `Exp` works fine with complex numbers (only in v9)

```
Exp[0.0 I - Range[1, 700, 0.001]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
Exp[0.0 I - Range[1, 800, 0.001]] // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.049367, True}
>
> {0.066757, True}

Edit:

I saw the answer with suggestion of compilation but for some reason it was removed. It is not very fast solution but it works. So I post it here

```
NExp = Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Exp[x], RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}];

NExp[-Range[1, 800, 0.001]]) // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.114772, True}

Comment: You mean, you want numbers outside the machine number zone to be clipped and kept as machine numbers?

Comment: @Rojo Yes, it is. I want it to be automatically and will not unpack arrays. Values like Exp[-800] appears in the studying something like Fermi-Dirac distribution for small temperatures. But these values is just zero.

Comment: In version 7 I get `{0.0080005, True}` and `{0.0160009, True}` as the output of the first two lines.  Apparently this is version specific; what are you running?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I ran it in v9, but in v7 I have the same result. May be it is platform-specific? I have Gentoo Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Will something like this work?

```
SetPrecision[Chop[N@#], MachinePrecision] & /@ Exp[-Range[1, 800]] //
   Developer`ToPackedArray // Developer`PackedArrayQ // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.004003, True}
> ```

The number has to first be converted to a numerical form with `N` or `Chop` won't do anything to it. Even if the number is large enough it isn't guaranteed to be converted to a machine precision number so we force that by calling `SetPrecision`. Conversion to a packed array isn't guaranteed either, so we have to call `ToPackedArray`. But, `ToPackedArray` won't convert a list if there will be a precision loss.

For a single value the following returns `True`.

```
MachineNumberQ@SetPrecision[Chop[N@Exp[-800]], MachinePrecision]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: This is interesting solution, but for my Range[1,800,**0.001**] it tooks about 3 seconds. It is 200 times slower than my solution...